# are you f---ing kidding me

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is the phrase "are you f---ing kidding me?" very rude, mild rude, or simply okay in everyday English? Plus, if the comment was "What heck are you doing?" is it acceptable to anyone? (I've heard that "heck" is normal in daily conversation)

> Washington (CNN)The announcement that former independent counsel Ken Starr is joining President Donald Trump's impeachment defense team surprised many on Friday, but one person, apparently, had an especially notable reaction to the news.

> "This is definitely an '**are you f---ing kidding me?**' kinda day," tweeted Monica Lewinsky, the former White House intern whose relationship with former President Bill Clinton led to his impeachment in 1998.

Source: [CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/01/17/politics/monica-lewinsky-ken-starr-senate/index.html)

Comment: It is very rude.

Comment: "What [the] heck are you doing?" is rude, since a polite query would be "What are you doing?" The first one implies that the speaker thinks they should not be doing whatever it is, i.e. expresses disapproval. It is a less rude substitute for "What the f--- are you doing?"

Comment: In some social groups it is the standard intensifier and is more or less equivalent to _very_. It has become more acceptable as the years have gone by but it still best avoided unless you are sure of your audience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the 'F' word, the expression "are you kidding me" is just an informal expression of surprise. Including that word makes it into a rude and aggressive statement, although the way it is said - tone of voice, context etc - has a part to play in that.

You might find the information on the website of the British Board of Film Classification useful. They usually class 'bad language' as either *mild, strong* or *coarse*. They deem the 'F' word to be "strong" language, but depending on the manner in which it is used may allow it to be used in a film suitable for 12-year-olds; if it is said in a violent or aggressive way, it is usually reserved for older audiences.

You asked if it was "everyday" - some people do make swearing a part of their everyday speech, but for the most part it is *not* acceptable in 'polite company'.

Comment: Thank you.                                                                                             It seems that  Monica Lewinsky has used it properly in the context given how Ken Starr treated her.